# Apache Spark: How can I use an RDD inside of my RDD loop?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is it possible to run a loop in Apache Spark parallelized and work with RDDs in this loop?

I want to use the correlation function for a cartesian product of values. This cartesian product is very large, so I was thinking about parallelizing the loop.

But if I parallelize the loop, can I still work with RDDs in this loop? 
Collecting and iterating is not an option.

Example:

Lets say I have products, date and price for the product in the Dataframe data.

The RDD materials is the list of all products that I have.

```
DataFrame data;
JavaRDD<String> materials;

JavaPairRDD<String, String> cartesian = materials.cartesian(materials);
```

In the next step I want to loop through all combinations of my cartesian RDD and filter the Dataframe for the Tuple values.

What I was thinking of is something like this:

```
cartesian.foreach(new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String, String>() {

    public void call (Tuple2<String, String> arg0) throws Exception {

    JavaRDD<Double> rdd1 = data.where(data.col("product").equalTo(arg0._1))
        .toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, Double>() {

        public Double call(Row arg1) throws Exception {
        return arg1.getDouble(2);
        }
    });

    JavaRDD<Double> rdd2 = ...

    }

    Statistics.corr(rdd1, rdd2);
});
```

This creates a memory leak as an error in the row where I try to create the rdd1. Is there any possible way to do something like this?
Is there any way to do work with RDDs in a parallelized loop?

How could I display the result of the correlation calculation? Is an accumulator the correct solution for this?

Comment: No, you cannot.